# ReactJs access "state" from a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menu

I have one file "Aboutmenu.js"

```js
export default class MenuExampleVerticalDropdown extends Component {
  state = { activeItem: ''}

  handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })

  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state
    

    return (
      <Menu secondary vertical>
        <Link to='/about'> <Menu.Item 
          name='General Information'
          active={activeItem === 'General Information'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        /></Link>
        <Link to='/about/history'><Menu.Item
          name='History'
          active={activeItem === 'History'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        /></Link>
        <Link to="/"><Menu.Item
          name='Prize Distribution'
          active={activeItem === 'Prize Distribution'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        /></Link>
        
      </Menu>
    )
  }
}
```

I import it in my about us page & will also import in aboutus/history; aboutus/distribution

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Container, Divider } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import MenuExampleVerticalDropdown from './AboutMenu'
const About = () => (
    <Layout>
    <div> 
        <h1>  About Us</h1>
        <hr />
    <MenuExampleVerticalDropdown style={{float:'left'}}/>
    <Container textAlign='left'>
      <b>General Information</b>
      <Divider />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
        Aenean massa strong. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
        ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla
        consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget,
        arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu
        pede link mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.
        Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend
        ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra
        nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel
        augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
        Aenean massa strong. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
        ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla
        consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget,
        arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu
        pede link mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.
        Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend
        ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra
        nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel
        augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi.
      </p>
    </Container>
  </div>
    </Layout>
  )
    export default About;
```

How do I get this to render automatically on every page I access? For example, when I get to aboutus/history it looks like in second picture. For now, I can only do that by clicking on the button :( 
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QENrt.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsLku.png)

Basically I tried to go to each page (aboutus, aboutus/history, aboutus/distribution) and my idea was to import MenuExampleVerticalDropdown from the aboutmenu.js (the first code snippet). I don't find any documentation or any related content to how I could access the state.

One thing I observed: if you modify the Aboutmenu.js line 2 to

```
state = { activeItem: 'General Information'}
```

it obviously shows 'General Information' on all pages like in picture 1

Comment: Forgot to mention: I can obviously hard code but I don't want to do that if there is any other option available

Comment: Instead of keeping the state in the menu component, you send it up to the parent. The parent's state will reflect the currently selected page and pass that as prop to the menu / render the pages conditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React, you can't directly access to the state of different components, unless you're using something like **Redux**, which is an overkill for your purpose.

In order to communicate components you need to perform a "***triangulation***" using the parent of the components as a bridge of communication, here there's a really good tutorial on how to achieve this: https://blog.logrocket.com/building-a-custom-dropdown-menu-component-for-react-e94f02ced4a1

Hope it helps, good luck!